# Is it possible to update node-weblit based application without new installation?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I'm plan to release my web application under node-webkit platform and allow users to install it on their local machine. But before, I need to understand how will I update this application?

I see the following two approaches:

1. Download a new version of new application and replace older one
2. Autoupdate node-webkit application like Google Chrome does (so users don't need to do anything except rebooting application).

I'm very interested how should I do the second approach? Could you share your experience with maintaining of your node-webkit based applications?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean update the node-webkit version or update your codebase?

Comment: yes. but I think I should to update node-webkit itself if needed

Comment: [This](https://github.com/edjafarov/node-webkit-updater) module could help.

Comment: Thank you very much. I need a time to explore this module